# Load HBase table in Spark SQL - NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a simple program to load data from HBase to Dataframe in Spark SQL. Somewhere old version of Spark is sneaking in, and I'm getting the error .. please advise

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
```

**Main Program**

```
object LoadHBase {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("HBase-Demo").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    val sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext
    val dataset = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").options(Map(
      "hbase.columns.mapping" -> "KEY_FIELD STRING :key, A_FIELD STRING c:a, B_FIELD STRING c:b",
      "hbase.table" -> "default:employee"
    )).load()
    dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_emp")
    sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) from temp_emp").show()
  }
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "scalaworks"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

resolvers += "Cloudera Repo" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.2.0-cdh5.10.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.2.0-cdh5.10.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.2.0-cdh5.10.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-spark" % "1.2.0-cdh5.10.0"
```

**Error stack trace**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:533)

    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 26 more
```

** Update **

Spark on Hbase is not supported on Spark 2.0

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark2_known_issues.html#ki_spark_on_hbase

Comment: The older version of Spark might be coming from `"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-spark" % "1.2.0-cdh5.10.0"` dependency.

Comment: yes ... looks like SparkOnHbase from Cloudera is not supported on Spark 2.0 https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark2_known_issues.html#ki_spark_on_hbase